# how to get data from own json file for each id and show inside the detail page for specific id

Tags: reactjs

**how to get data from own json file for each id and show inside the detail page for specific id**
this code is not working.please put your suggestion about my mistakes.i need your help..please help me.

**route is working successfully for each id but all data for specific id showing in a same page and this is same for all page.**

**Doctordata.js**

```
let arrobj = [
    {
      id : 1,
      src : './images1/image23.jpg',
      d_name : "Abir Ghosh",
      d_info : "Gastroenterology",
      primary :"Book Appointment"
    },
    {
      id : 2,
      src : './images1/image11.jpg',
      d_name : "Soma Dutta",
      d_info : "Orthopaedics",
      primary :"Book Appointment"
    },
    {
      id : 3,
      src : './images1/image4.jpg',
      d_name : "Sudan Ghosh",
      d_info : "Orthopaedics",
      primary :"Book Appointment"
    },
    {
      id : 4,
      src : './images1/image3.jpg',
      d_name : "Madusudan Ghosh",
      d_info : "Gastroenterology",
      primary :"Book Appointment"
    },
    {
      id : 5,
      src : './images1/image198.jpg',
      d_name : "Sudan Das ",
      d_info : "Kidney Transplant, Urology",
      primary :"Book Appointment"
    },
    {
      id : 6,
      src : './images1/image50.jpg',
      d_name : "Sankari Kumari Ghosh",
      d_info : "Plastic Surgery",
      primary :"Book Appointment"
    },
    {
      id : 7,
      src : './images1/image51.jpg',
      d_name : "Anisul Aslam",
      d_info : "Kidney Transplant, Urology",
      primary :"Book Appointment"
    },
    {
      id : 8,
      src : './images1/doctor1.jpg',
      d_name : "Suman Das",
      d_info : "Kidney Transplant, Urology",
      primary :"Book Appointment"
    }
  ];
  export default arrobj;
```

**App.js**

```
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Routes,Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import EachBlog from './EachBlog/EachBlog';


function App() {


  return (
    <>
    <Router>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/readeachblog/:id" element={<EachBlog/>} exact></Route>
      </Routes>
      
      </Router>
    </>

  );
}

export default App;
```

**Blog.js**

```
import './Blog.css'
import Blogdata from './Blogdata';
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
const Blog = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState(Blogdata);
    const filterResult = (catItem) => {
        const result = Blogdata.filter((curData) => {
            return curData.title === catItem;
        });
        setData(result);
    }
    return (
        <>
            <div className='back'><b>OUR BLOGS</b></div>
            <div className='containerfluid'>
                <div className='rowy'>
                    <div className='colmd'>
                        <button className="primary1" onClick={() => filterResult('Nutrition and diet')}>Nutrition and diet</button>
                        <button className="primary1" onClick={() => filterResult('Orthopaedics')}>Orthopaedics</button>
                        <button className="primary1" onClick={() => filterResult('Cardiology')}>Cardiology</button>
                        <button className="primary1" onClick={() => filterResult('Urology')}>Urology</button>
                        <button className="primary1" onClick={() => filterResult('Neurology')}>Neurology</button>
                        <button className="primary1" onClick={() => filterResult('General Surgery')}>General Surgery</button>
                    </div>
                    <div className='=colm'>
                        <div className='row'>
                            {data.map((values) => {
                                const { id, title, cardtitle, cardtext, srcd } = values;
                                return (
                                    <>
                                    
                                        <div className='wrapper2' key={id}>
                                            <div className="card" >
                                                <img src={srcd} className="cardimgtop" alt=" " />
                                                <div class="cardbody">
                                                    <h6 className='title'>{title}</h6>
                                                    <h5 className="cardtitle"><b>{cardtitle}</b></h5>
                                                    <p className="cardtext">{cardtext}</p>
                                                    <Link to={`/readeachblog/${values.id}`}><button className="primary">Read More</button></Link>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </>
                                );
                            })}

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
export default Blog;
```

**EachBlog.js**

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import './EachBlog.css'
import { Link, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import Doctordata from '../DoctorSection/Doctordata'
const EachBlog = () => {
    const {id} = useParams();
    const [ data, setData ] = useState(Doctordata);
   
  return (
    <>
    {data.map((data)=>{
        return(
            <>
            <Link to={`/readeachblog/${data.id}`}>
           
            <div className='datadiv' key={data.id}>
            <img className='srcBlog' src={data.srcBlog} alt={data.id}/> 
            <h1 className='firstparah'>{data.firstparah}</h1>
            <p className='firstpara'>{data.firstpara}</p>
            <h1 className='secondparah'>{data.secondparah}</h1>
            <p className='secondpara'>{data.secondpara}</p>
            <h1 className='thirdparah'>{data.thirdparah}</h1>
            <p className='thirdpara'>{data.thirdpara}</p>
            <h1 className='forthparah'>{data.forthparah}</h1>
            <p className='forthpara'>{data.forthpara}</p>
            </div>
          
            </Link>
            </>
        )
   })}
   </>
  )
}

export default EachBlog
```

Comment: map function is going to map your whole set of data into another array, that's why you certainly have all your data mapped in each route.

You could however try to filter the data on the useState like this and remove the "data.map" thing : 
`const [data, setData] = useState(Doctordata.find((data) => data.id === id);`

Comment: thank you so much sir...today i understand map method from you now it's very clear to me and code is working successfully.

Comment: @A.Vinuela, then how can the values from json data be displayed?

Comment: @SwarnaliGhosh can you add the final code? I encountered the same exact problem and couldn't fix it